# Fill a table with input from other table via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fill a table in one sheet with input from another table (different sheet "wsQuant") based on this function:

```
=CountIfs(Tabelle14[Question1];[@[Q1]];Tabelle14[Name];[@[Name]];Tabelle14[Participation];[@[Participation]])
```

This works, but since the table is very big, I am trying to realize it via VBA since the file always crashes (I assume it's too much calculation at once). My solution so far is:

```
Sub DataBase()

Dim wsQuant As Worksheet
Set wsQuant = Worksheets("quantitativ")

Range("I5").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs("wsQuant[$Z$4:$Z$1000]", [@[Q1]], "wsQuant[Name]", [@[Name]], "wsQuant[Participation]", [@[Participation]])

End Sub
```

This doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

I searched the entire day now and didn't find any answers.

Any help would be gratly appreciated.

EDIT:
Sample:

[Data from the questionaire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWgfW.png)

This is how the data is given. Answers to the questions on a scale from 1 to 5.

[List to be filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb5Ky.png)

This list should be filled through counting the answers that match the first 4 cloumns.

Comment: You might have to set your ranges to range variables, and use that in the `Countifs()`.  You're *not* using it like a worksheet function, so I don't know if simply putting the range names in there works.

Comment: Tables are `ListObjects` - so you should probably use the `DataBodyRange` of the `ListColumn`s in question as arguments in `WorksheetFunction.Countifs`.

Comment: This is really easy, can you provide a sample so I could show you exactly how?

Comment: I edited the question accordingly. Does this information help?